# Date on pandas ts.plot()

Tags: pandas

I cannot get the Dates to appear in my pandas time series plot. I have a time
series ts and I have given the output of ts below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series(df['res'])
# Date
# 2018-05-10    1.000000
# 2018-05-09    1.017333
# 2018-05-08    1.000000
# 2018-05-07    0.992783

ts.plot()
```

Even though the Series contains the dates, my plot only has the word 'Date' on
the x axis. How can I get it to label the x axis with the actual dates? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptom you describe (no dates on the x-axis) would occur if the index contained *date strings*. To convert the date strings to dates (of dtype `datetime64`), use

```
ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index)
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ts = pd.Series([1.000000, 1.017333, 1.000000, 0.992783],
               index=['2018-05-10', '2018-05-09', '2018-05-08', '2018-05-07'])

ts.index = pd.to_datetime(ts.index) 
ts.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]